# Speed up a massive number of inserts into multiple databases

Tags: java, mysql, database, guice, mybatis

I wrote a script that uses MyBatis to execute a massive number of inserts into **multiple databases**. The previous script didn't use MyBatis an was, more or less, **twice as fast** (25 min for a million records, 1 hour 10 minutes using MyBatis). I have tried different things, but I don't know exactly how to configure MyBatis to increase its performance. Some specific considerations about my problem and solution:

1. The databases are in a VPC, so **network time** is important.
2. I use **guice** to bind the mappers for each database. Connection information is set programmatically. The mappers are get then when I need to execute an insert.
3. The rows that need to be inserted are not sorted, so they are enqueued by database. When a queue reaches a given size, a **multirow insert** is executed. Can I use something better with injected mappers?
4. I use **pooled** connections. Does this mean that 3 connections are opened when the mapper is first used and then reused? If a given mapper is used only every few minutes, those idle connections are closed?
5. Sometimes I get this error randomly:

   ```
   org.apache.ibatis.transaction.TransactionException: Error configuring
   AutoCommit.  Your driver may not support getAutoCommit() or
   setAutoCommit(). Requested setting: false.
   Cause:
   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure    
   The last packet successfully received from the server was 4,030,088 milliseconds ago.
   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
   ```

What can I do to increase the performance and to avoid the communication error?

Comment: An obvious question: why do you use mybatisat all  if the previous solution was a lot faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1、it seems that you need to change your connection pool param.

database such as mysql may close a connection when it's idle for a target time interval, but the connection pool may not be noticed ,so when your mapper use a closed connection , the CommunicationsException occurs.

(1)if you use c3p0 ,you can specify the idle_test_period to solve this problem.

(2) or you can specify jdbc [Timeout Settings(Max Wait Time、Idle Timeout)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abehq/index.html)

2、connection pool has minSize and maxSize property , when your idle connection num is greater then minSize, the exceed part will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make optimization of mysql configuration to bulk insert : [enter link description here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)
It look like mybatis try to set autocommit to false, and that's a good optimization.
And I think it's better to have an instance of mapper by database and create 3 datasources with guice.

Another way is to use [sqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html) but it's a big break.